# Checking if 2 arrays have at least 1 equal value

Tags: php

Currently I have 2 array:

```
array(1, 2, 3, 4);
array(4, 5, 6, 7);
```

How can I check if there is at least one equal value in both of them? (The example above has 1 equal value => 4, so the function should return true).

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

*returns an array containing all the values of array1 that are present in all the arguments. Note that keys are preserved*

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$b = array(4, 5, 6, 7);
$c = array_intersect($a, $b);
if (count($c) > 0) {
    var_dump($c);
    //there is at least one equal value
}
```

you get

```
array(1) {
  [3]=>
  int(4)
}
```

Comment: then: `if (count($c)>0) doSomething();`

Comment: This is sub-optimal as the complete intersection is calculated, but you could stop as soon as one match is found. However, with small arrays, the efficiency of a built-in function will probably out-weigh the theoretical complexity issue. If you have large arrays you'll do better to sort them and then do a duel traverse removing the lowest from each until both empty or there is a match.

Comment: Ummm... just `if(array_intersect($a, $b))`

Comment: @RobertEgginton, you may want to traverse from the end of the array, removing the first element could force a `memmove`. That being said, already the sorts are going to be a killer.