# Finding a needle in a haystack *TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str*

Tags: python

i tried chaning from a list to a dictionary but it did not work

sorry for this newbie question, but i really tried doing it on my own for lots of time but it does not work.

I reduced the problem to finding a arrey of strings(needle) in another arrey of strings(hay). The rest i can do on my own

```
needle = [] 
for x in range(2015,2017):
    needle.append(str(x))


hay = [] 
for x in range(2015,2090):
    hay.append(str(x))

print(needle)
print(hay)

for a in needle:
    for b in hay:
        if needle[b] in hay[a]:
            print("Found!")
        else:        
            print("Not found!")
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  The title and comment are vague. Please all a *specific* question.

Comment: When you do `needle.append(str(x))` you're adding a value to an array; that value is a number that you've converted to a string via the `str` function.   When you access `needle[y]` you're asking for the value from array `needle` at index `y`... only `y` is a string.  The first item in the array would have index 0; i.e. `needle[0] = "2015"`, `needle[1] = "2016"`.

Comment: why is y a string. How to change it so that its an index like index i

Comment: `y` is a string because you inserted string values into needle (i.e. you converted the values to strings by using the `str` function.  However; even if it were an integer you'd have an issue; the values you inserted are the contents of the array; not it's indices.  i.e. If I list some numbers: `8, 12, 5` the first item in the list is `8`; there is no 8th item in the list.  For arrays the first item is index 0, the second index 1, etc.  So to see value 8 from my example you'd ask for the value with index 0 (`myArray[0]`).

Comment: are a and b indexes (0,1,2,3,4...)?

Comment: @mahle-majstr Or are they?... That's what you want/need them to be; but the code doesn't agree.  i.e. try just `for a in needle:` `print a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different numbers involved here - you have the value/element (i.e. the thing you're adding to the array) and the index; the element's position within that array.  When comparing your needle value with your haystack value you want to compare the values (which you're doing); but to get those values you want to look in the array in the relevant position (which you're not).

Instead, try something like this:

```py
needle = [] 
for x in range(2015,2017):
    needle.append(str(x))

hay = [] 
for x in range(2015,2022):
    hay.append(str(x))

print(needle)
print(hay)

for needleIndex in range(len(needle)):
    for hayIndex in range(len(hay)):
        if needle[needleIndex] == hay[hayIndex]:
            print("Found!")
        else:        
            print("Not found!")
```

This change means that instead of `a` being `'2015'`, `'2016'`, `'2017'` instead `needleIndex` is `0`,`1`,`2` and `needle[needleIndex]` is `'2015'`, `'2016'`, `'2017'`.

Hope that helps to clarify what's going on.

ps. For this example you don't need the indexes; you could just have

```py
for a in needle:
    for b in hay:
        if b == a:
            print("Found!")
        else:        
            print("Not found!")
```

Simpler still; you've shown that you're aware of the `in` operator; though you've been comparing individual values from the 2 arrays (hence I changed it to `==` above)... You can use your `in` operator like this:

```py
for a in needle:
    if a in hay:
        print("Found!")
    else:        
        print("Not found!")
```

You can also use the `array_intersect` function to check for all elements which exist in both arrays... More on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8679430/361842